Unable to turn on Java binding for opencv using brew
I'm trying to install opencv with Java bindings on MacOS Intel machine. I'm following the steps from: https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-x-under-macos
As per the docs, changing this option to ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF in -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON. Should do the job, but when I run "brew install --build-from-source opencv --verbose" in verbose mode it still takes it as OFF. Any way to override this from terminal itself or any way to make it work?. Attaching screenshots below:
Terminal Logs CMAKE
